# Where is kernel configuration stored on Linux target?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I'm working on an embedded ARM Debian Linux system.  The system ships with a default image on the SD card.  What I'd like to do is try and determine which kernel settings where used in building the kernel that's running on that card.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Check this http://serverfault.com/questions/51032/how-do-i-check-what-kernel-options-were-compiled-without-looking-at-boot-config

Comment: Thanks for the link, that is what I'm after, and will work if the kernel was compiled with CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC.  The file(s) didn't exist on my current system however.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system as well. Good answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming no copy can be found under `/boot` then:

If `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` is set then a compressed copy of the configuration will be found at `/proc/config.gz`

If `CONFIG_IKCONFIG` is set but not `CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC` the extract-ikconfig script can be used to extract the .config file from a kernel image file (http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/extract-ikconfig?id=HEAD)